# polygon editing - c4d subdivision surfaces 2023 tutorial

Tags: cinema-4d

In the tutorial video, when making the cube editable, the original box polygons wrap tightly onto the subdivisions -- and are seen as thicker lines amongst all the other polygons.

When viewing as isoparms, the original box polygons adhere to the surface:

[image]

In c4d 2023 you only see the original box polygons outside of the subdivided surface -- looks just like the original box:

[image]

A noob can kinda follow along, but the video shows something different that what's happening in c4d 2023.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out to be a setting:

Options > Isoline Editing

[image]